# "FTS" of Entity in GCP's Datastore

Tags: database, google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-cloud-platform

Let us assume I have some Entities type of "Employee".
I would like to list all of my Employees.

I've been browsing for hours the google-datastore docs, but I couldn't find out how to do this. Is there a specific query for this?

Comment: On which language?

Comment: Well, on each language is the same. This question was about how to do a "SELECT * FROM Employees" in gcp's Datastore.

Comment: Then, I though that it would be obvious to read documentation first and try to use provided query input for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Datastore Queries. Docs are [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-keys-only-query-go).
In your case, the query will have only `Kind` name (`Employees`).

For example in Go, you can query and list all of Employees like below:

```
query := datastore.NewQuery("Employee")
it := client.Run(ctx, query)
for {
        var employee Employee
        _, err := it.Next(&employee)
        if err == iterator.Done {
                break
        }
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error fetching next employee: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("employee %v\n", employee)
}
```